# Passing a query string to HtmlWebViewSource - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

I have the following code used in a Xamarin.Forms project:

```
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource { Html = @"<html>
                                                      <head>
                                                         <script async src=""https://URL""></script>
                                                      </head>
                                                      <body>
                                                          <div class=""class-name""></div>
                                                       </body>
                                                  </html>" };
 myWebView.Source = htmlSource;
```

Is it possible to define a query parameter - lets say q - **and pass a variable with a query string to the HTML code, before loading it in the WebView**?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) to inject the value in the object initializer:

```cs
// query
var q = 123;
// url with query
var url = $"https://www.somesite.com?q={q}";
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource 
{ 
    Html = @$"<html>
                  <head>
                     <script async src=""{url}""></script>
                  </head>
                  <body>
                      <div class=""class-name""></div>
                   </body>
              </html>"
};
```

Output of `htmlSource.Html`:

```
<html>
      <head>
         <script async src="https://www.somesite.com?q=123"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
          <div class="class-name"></div>
       </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that passing the query string as a parameter in the URL of the script does not work. That happens not only in the app, but also if I use the code in an HTML file.
For the JS to execute properly I have to pass the query string to the HTML's URL. Is this possible with the HtmlWebViewSource? If not, is it possible if I add a static HTML file in my app instead of using HtmlWebViewSource?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to achieve? *I have to pass the query string to the HTML's URL* what does that mean? Maybe you could update your question with an example? You also say in the question *and pass a variable with a query string to the HTML code* - could you clarify? Do you want to create a JS variable in the HTML string? @Costas

Comment: When I access my HTML file by visiting it's address, for example `C:\foo.html?q=query` on my hard disk, the file loads fine.

If I edit the HTML code of `foo.html` and add the query to the source of the script like this `<script async src="https://example.com/javascript.js?id=xxxxxxxxxx&q=query"></script>` and then open `C:\foo.html` with a browser nothing happens. The site doesn't load.

I guess that's the reason it doesn't load in the WebView too.

Comment: Oh I see - thank you for the explanation.  No, I don't think it's will be possible to pass a query string to an HTML file on disk. HTML doesn't know anything about query strings (it's just a string, well markup really).  On the web the server handles the query strings and returns HTML based on the query. But if the HTML file is on disk, why not load it into a string and update the value with your query value? Then pass that string to the `HtmlWebViewSource`. Would that work? @Costas

Comment: The file I created locally was for testing purposes.

In my Xamarin project I don't use a file. I have assigned the HTML code to the `htmlSource` variable. Is there an alternative way to pass the query string in that case?
If not, what if I create an HTML file and add it to my Xamarin project?

Comment: If you manually put this `<script async src="https://example.com/javascript.js?id=xxxxxxxxxx&q=query"></script>` in the HTML file and open in browser does it work? I guess you'll need to figure out how to get it working from a static HTML file, then apply that to the HTML in Xamarin. If it doesn't work in an HTML file in a browser then it's unlikely to work in Xamarin. Under which circumstances does `<script async src="https://example.com/javascript.js?id=xxxxxxxxxx&q=query"></script>` actually do what you want?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. That's exactly what I have already done. Please, read again my previous message.

If I use this line `<script async src="https://example.com/javascript.js?id=xxxxxxxxxx&q=query"></script>` in my HTML file, opening the file in a browser does not work properly.

On the other hand, if I use this URL as a source for the script: `<script async src="https://example.com/javascript.js?id=xxxxxxxxxx"></script>` and then open the file in the browser visiting this address `foo.html?q=query` then the file loads correctly.

How can I simulate the second method with Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Customizing a WebView**.

First you can create a custom renderer.

Then implement it on different platforms.

Finally, you can call and pass parameters.

For how to use it, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview#create-the-hybridwebview.

Comment: I am considering a solution with much less code than this. I'm considering of injecting JavaScript code that will make the changes after the code has loaded to the WebView.

Is there an event equivalent to [DOMContentLoaded](https://docs.w3cub.com/dom_events/domcontentloaded) in Xamarin.Forms WebView or only the `Navigated` event? I'm afraid that the [Navigating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.webview.navigating?view=xamarin-forms) event is not suitable because it executes when the loading starts.

Comment: When exactly do you need to load in Xamarin?

Comment: When a button is clicked.

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about JavaScript. Do you want to not use Create the HybridWebView at all?

Comment: No, I will give `HybridWebView` a try. I'm just polishing other parts of the code now.
How can I pass the query string with `HybridWebView` though. Do  I have to use a local HTML file or can I do it for the HTML code assigned to my variable?

Comment: For detailed usage of it, you can refer to: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/CustomRenderers/HybridWebView